# Удалить из файла слова которые содержат хотя бы одну цифру

Tags: python, python-3.x, текст

Исходные данные в текстовом файле (просто набор символов):

> fgsfgh8sfghfsh fgh f9sfh fgofgfgh7fsg6fgfg666fgfg   fsg sffg fg 7fgnsj9fs  fghsf 6sfg fg 7fsg fsg  8fsg fg adffhjh6fgn fgnfsgnf7sfnsfn fgvd ghg 7g

Пробую так:

```
file1 = open('test_5.txt', 'r+')
text1 = file1.read().split()
print(text1)
for words in range(0, int(len(text1))-1):
    if text1[words].isalpha() or text1[words].isdigit():
        print("None ")
    else:
        text1.pop(words)
```

Ошибка:

> ```
> if text1[words].isalpha() or text1[words].isdigit():
>     IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

Comment: int(len(text1)) - результат ``len()`` уже целое число, конвертировать дополнительно не требуется.

Comment: Что говорит ошибка?

Comment: Давайте я подскажу как оформлять вопрос: 1) `однако ошибка...` ошибку нужно бы указать 2) пример данных в файле тоже . Правка на кнопку `править`

Comment: А пока вы редактируете вопрос, важное правило: нельзя иди по массиву и удалять из него элементы. Нужно создавать новый массив и добавлять в него нужные элементы.

Comment: ААА, точно....я запутался уже совсем.Спасибо.Буду вникать дальше

Comment: Вы модифицируете список, по которому проходит цикл for — так нельзя делать, потому что после модификации `len` уменьшается, и в итоге ваш `words`, который создаётся на базе старого `len`, выходит за пределы списка

Comment: Вообще, не плохо было бы при работе с файлами использовать context manager. И дисциплинирует, и мусора в памяти не остается.

Answer (score 2):

Пример фильтрации:

```
# with open('test_5.txt') as f:
#     text = f.read()

text = "fgsfgh8sfghfsh fgh f9sfh fgofgfgh7fsg6fgfg666fgfg fsg sffg fg 7fgnsj9fs fghsf 6sfg fg 7fsg fsg 8fsg fg adffhjh6fgn fgnfsgnf7sfnsfn fgvd ghg 7g"

items = [word for word in text.split() if not any(c.isdigit() for c in word)]
print(items)  # ['fgh', 'fsg', 'sffg', 'fg', 'fghsf', 'fg', 'fsg', 'fg', 'fgvd', 'ghg']
```

Вариант через функциональный стиль:

```
items = list(filter(lambda word: not any(c.isdigit() for c in word), text.split()))
print(items)  # ['fgh', 'fsg', 'sffg', 'fg', 'fghsf', 'fg', 'fsg', 'fg', 'fgvd', 'ghg']
```

---

Код `not any(c.isdigit() for c in word)` можно заменить регуляркой `not re.search('\d', word)`, пример:

```
import re
items = [word for word in text.split() if not re.search('\d', word)]
print(items)  # ['fgh', 'fsg', 'sffg', 'fg', 'fghsf', 'fg', 'fsg', 'fg', 'fgvd', 'ghg']
```

Comment: Спасибо.Я сделал так:
    res=[]
    for words in text1:
        if words.isalpha() or words.isdigit():
            res.append(words)
так ведь можно???

Comment: @Валерий, используйте символ \` , чтобы в комментарии код описывать